# AngularJS - Remove custom event listener

Tags: angularjs

I have a non AngularJS snippet that is communicating with my AngularJS modules via custom events. Each of these AngularJS modules represents a different route. When I am leaving each route `$onDestroy` is triggered but does not remove the event listener. What am I missing to un-register my custom event?

**Non AngularJS HTML Snippet**

```
<script>
function sendEvent() {
    const payload = getPayload();
    const event = new CustomEvent('myCustomEvent', { payload });
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}
</script>

<button onclick="sendEvent()">Send Custom Event</button>
```

**AngularJS Component**

```
Class ModuleA {
    $onInit() {
        this.$window.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', this.onCustomEventClick.bind(this));
    }

    $onDestroy() {
        this.$window.removeEventListener('myCustomEvent', this.onCustomEventClick.bind(this), false);
    }
}

Class ModuleB {
    $onInit() {
        this.$window.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', this.onCustomEventClick.bind(this));
    }

    $onDestroy() {
        this.$window.removeEventListener('myCustomEvent', this.onCustomEventClick.bind(this), false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `bind` it will create a new function and return it instead of modifying the function itself. So the even listeners you provide to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` are different functions, thus the registered ones are not removed.

To solve it, call `bind` once in `$onInit` and keep a reference to the returned function and always use that reference:

```
Class ModuleB {
    $onInit() {
        this.onCustomEventClick = this.onCustomEventClick.bind(this)
        this.$window.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', this.onCustomEventClick);
    }

    $onDestroy() {
        this.$window.removeEventListener('myCustomEvent', this.onCustomEventClick, false);
    }
}
```